# Qual a utilidade do pdoxusrs.net?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Olá,

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma aplicação Delphi 7 com paradox (acredito que com BD isso também ocorra) que se utiliza do aquivo pdoxusrs.net, porém outras aplicações a usam.

Alguém pode explicar como isso funciona de fato, estou procurando e encontro mais solução de problemas do que uma explicação.

Answer (score 1):

Resumidamente, esse arquivo é onde todos os BDEs da rede local bloqueiam e liberam o acesso aos registros das tabelas que uma aplicação está utilizando (lock pessimista). 
Por isso é importante que os BDEs apontem para o mesmo arquivo, caso contrário duas aplicações poderão corromper uma tabela ao tentar altera-la ao mesmo tempo

Answer (score 0):

Bom, pergunta parece que difícil de responder, então fui a procura de uma resposta, não ousarei traduzir a resposta para não complicar, então segue o endereço onde encontrei uma resposta mais convincente do que ocorre com este arquivo.

http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/db12.htm

A maioria das resposta que encontre fala em como resolver o problema e não em entender o que realmente acontece, então esta é um esclarecimento sobre alguns problemas com este arquivo.